# Reading a file over a network path

Tags: java, file-io

I have this weird issue, when I use

```
File FileToRead = new File("\\\\MYSERVER\\MYFOLDER\\MYFOLDER\\MYPICTURE.JPG");
```

to read a file over a network, all I get is a null pointer exception. Normally a local path works with this, but when on a network path, I just couldn't manage to get it to work. Any ideas?

PS: oh and my network connection seems to work, no issues when accessing data in windows explorer...

More of the code:

```
File FileToRead = new File("file://DOKSERVICE/Somefolder/ProductImage/01001.JPG");
//File FileToRead = new File("c:\\dog.jpg"); local test
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(FileToRead);
BufferedImage resizedimage = new BufferedImage(260, 260,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB ); 
Graphics2D g = resizedimage.createGraphics();  
g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 260, 260, null);  
g.dispose(); 
picture.setIcon(new ImageIcon(image));
```

Comment: I'm guessing it is something to do with the case. Is your full path exactly that way, in all caps? Windows is case-insensitive. Java need not be.

Comment: Can you post the code that actually causes the error or results in a null reference?  The line you listed should never be null, on any Java platform.

Comment: Are you certain your UNC reference points to a *share* and not to a folder, eg \\\\MYSERVER\\SHARENAME\\FOLDER\\FOLDER\\MYPICTURE.JPG. If the second part of your example above truly is a folder name, not a share, the reference will not resolve.

Answer (score 8):

Just specify the file path as URI:

```
File FileToRead = new File(new URI("file://MYSERVER/MYFOLDER/MYFOLDER/MYPICTURE.JPG"));
```

**EDIT** note that that string is an URI! It cannot contain spaces so you have to replace them with "%20" to make it work.

Comment: Tried it and got: javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file! :(

Comment: @Sin5k4 can you post the file path here? The exact one you use, if possible.

Comment: the path is:String filepath = "file:\\\\DOKSERVICE\\Dokumaortak\\ProductImage\\"+generatefilename+".JPG";

Comment: Does _generatedfilename_ contain some character that should be encoded? With forward slash instead of backslash it doesn't work?

Comment: it simply does this:       generatefilename=generatefilename.replace("/", "_");And just checked it via debugger and it seems to generate it normally,looks like it's a resolve issue.

Comment: Is there any other character that should not be used in URI? Spaces? _Special_ character or non ANSI?

Comment: Nope,no spaces or any special chars :/

Comment: This code doesn't seem to work.  You probably mean new File(new URI())