# Access a file in network path

Tags: java, file, jakarta-ee, filepath

I have a wav file in network path i could able to access it from run as \192.106.100.35\Recorded files
from that folder i have to access 536.wav file ,i tried [like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10416736/reading-a-file-over-a-network-path)

code

```
File file = new File("file://192.106.100.35/Recorded%20files/536.wav");
    FileInputStream fis;
    byte[] buffer=null;

fis = new FileInputStream(file);
buffer= new byte[fis.available()];
fis.read(buffer);
fis.close();
```

but gives

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:\192.106.100.35\Recorded%20files\536.wav (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.pointel.chart.PlayAudio.doGet(PlayAudio.java:39)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:690)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:286)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Oct 31, 2013 5:51:02 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet PlayAudio threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:83)
    at com.pointel.chart.PlayAudio.doGet(PlayAudio.java:62)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:690)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:286)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`java.io.File` only works with the local harddisk. Use `java.net.URL` instead for network resources:

```
new URL("http://192.106.100.35/Recorded%20files/536.wav");
```

for this to work, you need a server on `192.106.100.35` which supports the HTTP protocol and which exposes the file as `/Recorded%20files/536.wav`

Other options are NFS or SMB (to mount a remote file system on the local computer; afterwards, you can use `File` again).

Comment: thanks, is there no other way to access the file in  windows remote shared folder by java code

Comment: Map the network share using the normal tools. That will make the remote file visible in the local file system and Java will be able to load it.

Answer (score 0):

Short version is you can't do that at all.

[Javadoc here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html)  I'm guessing maybe this is a windows share?  But how you get at it depends on the server side.  If you can actually mount the remote device e.g.(NFS/Samba/CIFS) then you could salvage this approach.  But if it is like an HTTP server you are completely barking up the wrong tree.