# Reading File from a Shared Path on Windows

Tags: java

```
String dirPath = "\\\\tent\\AAA\\Apps\\DCS\\DCMS\\PASE2E\\PAS\\Home\\ArchivePDF";
        FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
        ftpClient.connect("192.168.20.143");
        ftpClient.login("ggh2ban", "password");
        ftpClient.setRemoteVerificationEnabled(false);
        ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
        FTPFile[] files = ftpClient.listFiles(dirPath);
        for (FTPFile file : files) {
            String details = file.getName();
            if(file.isFile())
            {
                System.out.println("Name is "+details);
             }
```

This is my code to read files from ArchivePDF folder. its getting the following Error. Anyone with any ideas?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:351)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:213)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
    at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:182)
    at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:203)
    at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:296)
    at com.file.FTPFileOps.main(FTPFileOps.java:20)
```

FTPFileOps.java:20= the IP-Address Line! I am accesing my Client machine via Remote Desk Conn. and the file is in the shared Network, address of which is mentioned above.

Thanks!

Comment: is your ftp server running?

Comment: The error have nothing to do with Windows or shared paths, but with the FTP connection.

Comment: Are you trying to access NetBIOS/Samba path via FTP? I don't know how rdesktop attaches remote folders... but I doubt it is FTP.

Comment: You might want to check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10416736/reading-a-file-over-a-network-path or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1682194/java-read-file-from-network-device .

Answer (score 0):

Windows shares don't use the FTP protocol but the SMB protocol.

On a Windows machine, to connect using the current user, you may just open the file using `java.io.File`:

```
new File("\\\\tent\\AAA\\Apps\\DCS\\DCMS\\PASE2E\\PAS\\Home\\ArchivePDF");
```

If you want to specify another username/password or run on a non windows machine, you can use  the JCIFS library (http://jcifs.samba.org/) and do something like:

```
SmbFile file = new SmbFile("smb://ggh2ban:password@192.168.20.143/tent/AAA/Apps/DCS/DCMS/PASE2E/PAS/Home/ArchivePDF");
```

And then use the JCIFS APIs to navigate on the remote file system.