# Copy the Data inside Pen Drive to a local location using java in windows and linux

Tags: java, linux, jakarta-ee

I will be grateful if some one respond quickly.
I need to copy the content inside pendrive to a new local location in windows as well as linux.

Comment: a) off topic for SO and b) why can't you just copy it?

Answer (score 0):

As long as pen drive attached and detected by system, can use any IO api to copy the content.

Just specify the file path as URI:

****File FileToRead = new File(new URI("file://MYSERVER/MYFOLDER/MYFOLDER/MYPICTURE.JPG"));****

refer the link
[Reading a file over a network path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10416736/reading-a-file-over-a-network-path)

Comment: Hi Amarpal, is there any way to copy the content from the pendrive without  using the exact location for the pendrive.

Comment: Can use the relative path... other then that I can't think for any solution.