# Open a PDF file from shared path in Java

Tags: java

I have a PDF file in my shared path. I have tried accessing it through the normal method but it's not happening. How to access that file?

This is the code I have tried.

```
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.PdfTextExtractor;

/**
 * This class is used to read an existing
 *  pdf file using iText jar.
 * @author codesjava
 */
public class PDFReadExample {
  public static void main(String args[]){
    try {
    //Create PdfReader instance.
    PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader("D:\\testFile.pdf");    

    //Get the number of pages in pdf.
    int pages = pdfReader.getNumberOfPages(); 

    //Iterate the pdf through pages.
    for(int i=1; i<=pages; i++) { 
      //Extract the page content using PdfTextExtractor.
      String pageContent = 
        PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(pdfReader, i);

      //Print the page content on console.
      System.out.println("Content on Page "
                          + i + ": " + pageContent);
      }

      //Close the PdfReader.
      pdfReader.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

But what if my path is like this:
**http://team.net/po/kc ape/Platform%20Symbol/form%7D**

Comment: What is a normal method? Please show us your code.

Comment: normal in the sense I just tried the method to access a file from local.. @harmonica141

Comment: Code please. Your question is not answerable like this.

Comment: Please fine the edit @harmonica141

Comment: Why is there a double backslash in the filepath `PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader("D:\\testFile.pdf");` or did you just shorten the path?

Comment: Please try it with "D:/testFile.pdf"

Comment: What happens when you run the code?  Do you get any errors?

Comment: I tested your code without any issues, check whether your IDE or JRE has access to the file

Comment: @EduardoEljaiek I am also able to access the file but the thing is what if the path is directed to shared network? How to access then?

Comment: @GiridharKumar you could try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10416736/reading-a-file-over-a-network-path. Please edit your question in order to be more specific

Comment: @EduardoEljaiek Please find the edit i.e path is a link

Comment: `D:\\testFile.pdf` should be replaced with `D:\\\\testFile.pdf`, `\ ` in a string is used to  write special characters like `\n` or `\r`.

Comment: Is your questing how you can fetch the PDF content if it is not on your file system but rather accessible through another protocol such as HTTP? I find it unclear if you have problem loading it from D:\\ (as per your example) or HTTP (last line of your question).

Comment: Yes @RogerLindsjö. The PDF is not in my file system but can accessible through HTTP

Answer (score 2):

PdfReader has a constructor which accepts an InputStream.
To access content behind an URL you can use the class URL:

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.io.InputStream;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader;

URL url=new URL("http://...").
InputStream is = url.openStream();
PdfReader reader=new PdfReader(is);
```